# On choosing statistical test to see the effect of 2 types of essential oils on e.coli

Tags: modeling, biostatistics

So I'm trying to see the effect of 2 different types of essential oils on e.coli (Grade 12 student - this is for my IB Biology EE)

What I did was that I increased the concentrations of the oils from 10% to 20%, 30%, 40%, and 50%. I used the disk diffusion tests and measured the inhibition zones formed. I also had a positive control being an antibiotic so I compare with that too. In addition to that I combined the two oils in 5 different ratios (1:5, 2:4, 3:3, 4:2, 5:1) to see if there's a synergistic effect. So if I'm not wrong, I've got 2 independent variables and 1 dependent variable (not sure if the combination ratios are variables too somewhere?).

Based off of what I've read so far, there are one-way and two-way ANOVA tests, as well as t-tests, and Tukey's HSD test. I cannot tell which are the most relevant in my case. I also have no idea what method to use for measuring synergy.

Comment: Hello and welcome to CrossValidate. Can you provide a dummy table/sample of your data?

Comment: Might also help if you add what's your academic background and level so that response can be catered to your needs.

Comment: I have not yet finished tabulating the data, but once I do I might be able to provide a dummy table. Do not know how long that will take since I'm quite slow, but I'd appreciate if I could get some general idea as to how I can approach this.

Comment: How do you measure effect? Survival?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I followed the disk diffusion test (Kirby Bauer Method). So the larger the zone of inhibition produced by the oil, the more sensitive the bacterial strain, meaning more of its growth was inhibited. The diameter of that zone is measured across 10 trials per concentration for each oil. Also measured that for when I combined the oils in 5 different ratios.

Comment: Please add that new information as an edit to the post! We want posts to be self-contained, and comments on this site are often seen by very few people, and can be removed